# Grafana docker image with zabbix plugin

Tags: docker, grafana, zabbix

I want to add `zabbix` data source into my grafana in kunernetes, for that I created a custom image using [this](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/packaging/docker/custom/Dockerfile) dockerfile and added

`ARG GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS="alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app"`

Then build the image and ran.

But when I logged to that docker container and run `grafana-cli plugins ls`, it shows nothing.

How can I create a docker image with zabbix datasource into that?

Comment: Did you volume mount the `/var/lib/grafana-plugins` the folder by any chance

Comment: @TarunLalwani At the moment, I just created docker image and ran it with `docker run` and then connected to it. Yet not deployed in K8

Comment: I think you need to add `RUN grafana-cli plugins install $GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS`

Comment: @TarunLalwani You mean,official dockerfile and then add this line? [this](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/packaging/docker/Dockerfile)

Comment: Yes. Because in official image this variable is picked at the start. Since you use it as a ARG instead of ENV, this is not picked up when the image is boot. Either add a `ENV GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=$GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS` to move the ARG to ENV, but this will still allow someone outside the image to change the list and break your image. So best is to use the `RUN` command I shared earlier

Comment: @TarunLalwani I had checked with docker run, it has this plugin, but when I deploy with K8, it doesnt have plugin in `/var/lib/grafana/plugin`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229981/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-sachith-muhandiram).

Answer (score 1):

Since the base image use the `GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS` environment variable at run-time, it is best for you to set it during the run of the image

While running in `docker run -e GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS="alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app" ...`, if you use `docker-compose` or `kubernetes` then you should pass that value in environment variables.

If you want to install the plugin in the image you can use below statement

```
RUN grafana-cli plugins install $GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS
```

But this will not work if you volume mount `/var/lib/grafana-plugins` to a folder on host

Comment: I had created docker image with proper zabbix datasource, but its not shown in kubernetes service.  and could you please tell me how this volume-mount thing should be done?